# How to Delete value from Firebase realtime database by key in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have realtime database in firebase it look like this

[image]

Now I want to delete value by key in android (java).

I have tried this code

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.child("coating").child("88").removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

        Toast.makeText(activity, "on success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(activity, "on success"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I get success response in onSuccess Method but value in database is not deleted.

Comment: Your code is correct and it should work. How do you check the existence of `88`, in the console?

Comment: you can just set value to empty  "" and on its complete listener do your work

Answer (score 0):

As per this document

[check out last para about delete and update ui](https://medium.com/a-practical-guide-to-firebase-on-android/updating-and-deleting-from-your-firebase-database-bc8d39573829)